# What is the distance between 2 cities?

Tags: earth, distances

Both Quito and Kampala lie on the Equator. The longitude of Quito is 82°30'W and that of Kampala is 37°30'E. What is the distance from Quito to Kampala?
A) along the shortest surface path
B) along a direct through the Earth path?
Please help me visualize it with a figure. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hardly an astronomy question, but I like drawing, so here you are:

[image: Earth from above]

Longitudes are measured from the Greenwich meridian, so the angle between Kampala and Quito is
$$\theta_\mathrm{Q} + \theta_\mathrm{K} = 82.5^\circ + 37.5^\circ = 110^\circ.$$
(remember that $0^\circ30' = 0.5^\circ$).
The shortest surface path is along Equator. Since $110^\circ$ is $\frac{110^\circ}{360^\circ} \simeq 0.3$ times the [circumference of Earth at Equator](https://www.google.dk/#q=circumference+of+Earth+at+Equator), the length of path A (the dashed line) is
$$\mathrm{A}:\,\,d = 0.3 \times 40,075\,\mathrm{km} = 12,245\,\mathrm{km}$$

For path B (the solid line), you need a bit more  trigonometry. The radius of Earth is $R = 40,075\,\mathrm{km}\,/\,2\pi = 6,378\,\mathrm{km}$. The rest will be left as an exercise.

Comment: Strange mixture of significant figures. The radius to match the circumference you have used is 6378 km.

Comment: @RobJeffries: That's because the 6371 km is an "average" over the whole Earth. At the equator, it is [6378 km](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#Equatorial_radius), as you say. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll fix it.